# Having difficulty installing ruby-filemagic gem on new RHEL6 server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, bundler

It appears to be looking for the libmagic.so.1 file. I have that file. It is located in /usr/lib64. I am not running this installation as the root user.

I am also using rvm and Bundler. This is the result of my "bundle" command, when it gets to the ruby-filemagic line in my Gemfile:

```
[server@mine ext]$ ruby extconf.rb --with-magiclib
checking for magic_open() in -ltrue... no
*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

UPDATE:

Here are the results of the mkmf.log:

```
have_library: checking for magic_open() in -ltrue... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I. -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.    -g -O2  -fPIC   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-static -ltrue  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:3: error: ‘magic_open’ undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:3: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
conftest.c:3: error: for each function it appears in.)
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))magic_open; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I. -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.    -g -O2  -fPIC   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-static -ltrue  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltrue
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { magic_open(); return 0; }
/* end */
```

---

I can't figure out what to do to make this work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed to do:

```
yum install file-devel
```

That apparently contains the libmagic header files that the filemagic ruby gem required in order to compile. It worked like a champ after that.

Comment: `file-devel` indeed seems to be the devel package for `file-libs`!

Answer (score 19):

Had same problem on Ubuntu 12.04. Just installed `libmagic-dev` package through following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagic-dev
```

Answer (score 10):

On a Mac, using homebrew:

```
sudo brew install libmagic
```

Comment: Hey, I'm still getting `checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... no` got any ideas?

Comment: First make sure libmagic actually got installed properly. Try `ls -al /usr/local/include/|grep magic` and verify that `magic.h` is there)

Comment: file magic.h is there but I have the same error
but the initial error with most recent ruby-filemagic i believe is this
ld: library not found for -lgnurx
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on OpenSuse 11.3. This helped:

```
zypper install file-devel
```

Comment: Adding a comment here for people landing via install failures of "ruby-magic" on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

1. Search Tumbleweed history for the relevant old packages, if needed (e.g. https://download.opensuse.org/history/20230801/ - `cat rpm.list`, then append the package path to the url to find the `.rpm` file download path). I needed 5.44 file-magic, libmagic1, file-devel
2. When installing, set the `MAGIC_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES` env variable (to anything) - e.g. `gem build ruby-magic.gemspec && MAGIC_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true gem install ./ruby-magic-0.6.0.gem`