# How do I install ruby-filemagic on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I found a few existing questions that ask this, but none of the answers in them work.

[Trying to install ruby-filemagic on Snow Leopard using brew rather than ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190961/trying-to-install-ruby-filemagic-on-snow-leopard-using-brew-rather-than-ports)

[Having difficulty installing ruby-filemagic gem on new RHEL6 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338960/having-difficulty-installing-ruby-filemagic-gem-on-new-rhel6-server)

They all point to this page as the answer

https://gist.github.com/eparreno/1845561

Except that doesn't work either. I still get the following error.

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-magic-include=/usr/local/include --with-magic-lib=/usr/local/lib/'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-filemagic:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-magic-include=/usr/local/include --with-magic-lib=/usr/local/lib/
checking for main() in -lgnurx... no
checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... no
*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-magic-dir
    --without-magic-dir
    --with-magic-include=${magic-dir}/include
    --with-magic-lib=${magic-dir}/
    --with-gnurx-dir
    --without-gnurx-dir
    --with-gnurx-include
    --without-gnurx-include=${gnurx-dir}/include
    --with-gnurx-lib
    --without-gnurx-lib=${gnurx-dir}/
    --with-gnurxlib
    --without-gnurxlib
    --with-magiclib
    --without-magiclib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-filemagic-0.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-filemagic-0.7.0/ext/filemagic/gem_make.out
```

So what changed? In the error that is mentioning about mkmf.log, I see a lot of compilation stuff in the log file, so I don't know where exactly the error is. It looks like the following:

```
have_library: checking for main() in -lgnurx... -------------------- no

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib/ -L. -L/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib/ -L. -L/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -lgnurx  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:5:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'main'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 6: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 7: {
 8:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 9:     printf("%p", &t);
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
/* end */

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib/ -L. -L/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -lgnurx  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:5:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'main' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { main(); return 0; }
              ^
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lgnurx
conftest.c:5:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'main' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { main(); return 0; }
              ^
1 warning generated.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int t(void) { main(); return 0; }
 6: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 7: {
 8:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 9:     printf("%p", &t);
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... -------------------- no

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib/ -L. -L/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -lmagic  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:5:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'magic_open'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))magic_open; return 0; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))magic_open; return 0; }
 6: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 7: {
 8:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 9:     printf("%p", &t);
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
/* end */

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib/ -L. -L/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.0.0 -lmagic  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:5:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'magic_open' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { magic_open(); return 0; }
              ^
1 warning generated.
conftest.c:5:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'magic_open' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int t(void) { magic_open(); return 0; }
              ^
1 warning generated.
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib//libmagic.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib//libmagic.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_magic_open", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-d6cdee.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int t(void) { magic_open(); return 0; }
 6: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 7: {
 8:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 9:     printf("%p", &t);
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
/* end */

--------------------
```

The main problem appears to be this

```
conftest.c:5:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'magic_open'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))magic_open; return 0; }
```

I don't know C++, so I don't know what the problem with magic_open is

Any ideas?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmagic-dev` helps?

Comment: This is on Mac OS X. I wish this was Linux. I'd be past this by now, heh

Answer (score 12):

a few years later...  try this on a Mac.

`brew install libmagic`

Hoping this helps anyone else coming across the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to accept xcode license
for example, type `sudo clang` and follow the shown procedure

Comment: I don't think the Xcode license is related to the original poster's problem. After all, clang *does* seem to be working.